# Adding FontAwsome Icon + Text gives me error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I have this method with a textArea:

```
 DropdownExampleClearable = () => <Dropdown placeholder="Status" clearable options={options} selection />
```

And this is the Options that it has:

```
const options = [
 { key: 1, text: (<i className="far fa-edit"/> + "OK"), value: 1 },
 { key: 2, text: <i className="far fa-edit"/>, value: 2 },
]
```

The first key will display '[Object object]OK'

The second key will display the desired Icon but if i add any text the icon wont show anylonger.

Any suggestions on how to get the icon+text to display would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSX is just sugar for `React.createElement` calls](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwSwBAxgNghgznAcjAtgUwLwCIBmMBOYeAtGgCYgAuWA9AHxA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.3&externalPlugins=), so you can't add a string to that with `+ "OK"`.

You could instead wrap the icon and the text in another React element and use that.

```
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: <span><i className="far fa-edit" /> OK</span>, value: 1 },
  { key: 2, text: <i className="far fa-edit" />, value: 2 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <p> <i className="far fa-edit"> OK </i>  </p>
```